# Thymeleaf @Valid LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, thymeleaf

I have problem with validation in thymeleaf. My case is to save Employee with Position and Role-s. Those two "fields" cause LazyInitializationException when validation has errors. If validation passed Employee will be save to DB and everything is ok. Please give me some advice, what I am doing wrong or how can I fix it.

Please look for my code below:

EmployeeController:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController extends BaseCrudController {

    // (........)

    @RequestMapping(value = urlFragment + "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createEmployee(Model model) {
        prepareEmployeeForm(model);
        return "crud/employee/create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = urlFragment + "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processNewEmployee(Model model, @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") @Valid EmployeeForm employeeForm, BindingResult result) {

        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            User user = employeeFormService.getUserFromEmployeeForm(employeeForm);
            try {
                userService.merge(user);
                model.addAttribute("success", true);
                prepareEmployeeForm(model);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                model.addAttribute("error", true);
            }
        } else {
            initCollections(employeeForm, model);
        }

        return "crud/employee/create";
    }

    private void initCollections(EmployeeForm employeeForm, Model model)
    {
        employeeForm.setAllAvailableRoles(roleRepository.findAll());
        employeeForm.setAllAvailablePositions(positionRepository.findByEnabledTrueOrderByNameAsc());
        model.addAttribute("employeeForm", employeeForm);
    }

    private void prepareEmployeeForm(Model model) {
        EmployeeForm employee = new EmployeeForm();

        employee.setAllAvailablePositions(positionRepository.findByEnabledTrueOrderByNameAsc());
        employee.setAllAvailableRoles(roleRepository.findAll());

        model.addAttribute("employeeForm", employee);
    }
}
```

EmployeeForm:

```
public class EmployeeForm extends BaseForm {

    @Length(min = 2, max = 45)
    private String firstName = "";

    // (........)

    private Position position;

    private Collection<Role> roles;

    private Collection<Position> allAvailablePositions;

    private Collection<Role> allAvailableRoles;

    public EmployeeForm() {
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Collection<Position> getAllAvailablePositions() {
        return allAvailablePositions;
    }

    public void setAllAvailablePositions(Collection<Position> allAvailablePositions) {
        this.allAvailablePositions = allAvailablePositions;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getAllAvailableRoles() {
        return allAvailableRoles;
    }

    public void setAllAvailableRoles(Collection<Role> allAvailableRoles) {
        this.allAvailableRoles = allAvailableRoles;
    }
}
```

employeeForm.html

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/panel/employee/create}" th:object="${employeeForm}" method="post">

                <!--(......)-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label th:text="#{position}">Position</label>
<!--(Line 57 cause LazyInitializationException)--><select th:field="*{position}" class="form-control">
                            <option th:each="positionQ : *{allAvailablePositions}"
                                    th:value="${{positionQ}}"
                                    th:text="${positionQ.name}">Position name
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label th:text="#{permissions}">Permissions</label>
                        <th:block th:each="role : *{allAvailableRoles}">
                            <p>
                                <input type="checkbox" th:id="${{role}}" th:value="${{role}}" th:field="*{roles}"/>
                                <label th:for="${{role}}"
                                       th:text="#{${role.name}}">Role name</label>
                            </p>
                        </th:block>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </form>
```

Trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringSelectFieldAttrProcessor' (crud/employee/employeeForm:57)
```

root cause:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringSelectFieldAttrProcessor' (crud/employee/employeeForm:57)
```

root cause

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringSelectFieldAttrProcessor' (crud/employee/employeeForm:57)
```

root cause

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I will be really glad for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your hibernate session is closed. The pattern open-session-in-view solves this issue. You can use spring-boot where it is the default or look at the configuration in [fuwesta-sampe](https://github.com/opensource21/fuwesta/blob/237d584e895480931f362d6ef1be15f9ee3ad024/fuwesta-sample/src/main/java/de/ppi/samples/fuwesta/config/WebMvcConfig.java#L145).

The cleaner approach is to ensure that the data are complete loaded before you close the session. This means a service layer should navigate to each entity or use eager fetching.